# Entity Framework Code First - Virtual Property Column Naming

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework-4

I'm using EF Code First (4.3.1) on a personal ASP.NET MVC 3 project, with a very simple domain model, and I'm almost at the point where EF will generate the DB schema the way I want it to.

The domain model has two classes: `Painting` and `Gallery`. Each `Painting` belongs to a single `Gallery`, and the `Gallery` has two virtual properties pointing to `Painting`: One to indicate which of the painting is it's cover image, and one for which of the paintings is the Slider image displayed on the home page.

The classes are as follow. I've removed some annotations and irrelevant properties to make it readable.

```
public class Gallery
{
    public Gallery()
    {
        Paintings = new List<Painting>();
    }

    [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
    [Key]
    public int GalleryId { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
    [Column("LaCover")]
    public Painting Cover { get; set; }

    [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
    [Column("ElSlider")]
    public Painting Slider { get; set; }

    [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
    public virtual List<Painting> Paintings { get; set; }
}
```

and painting:

```
public class Painting
{
    [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
    [Key]
    public int PaintingId { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public int GalleryId { get; set; }

    [Column("GalleryId")]
    [ForeignKey("GalleryId")]
    [InverseProperty("Paintings")]
    public virtual Gallery Gallery { get; set; }

    public string Filename { get; set; }
}
```

It generates a correct db schema for both classes and its relationships, the only small issue I have is that I haven't found a way to control the column names it gives to the virtual properties of `Cover` and `Slider` in the `Gallery` table.

It'll name them `Cover_PaintingId` and `Slider_PaintingId`.

I tried using the `[Column("columnNameHere")]` attribute, but that doesn't affect it at all. As in "I typed a certain non related word and it didnt show up in the schema".

I'd like to name it `CoverPaintingId`, without the underscore.

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [ForeignKey](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.schema.foreignkeyattribute%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) attribute lets you define the property that will act as your foreign key if you want it to exist within your model:

```
[ForeignKey("CoverPaintingId")]
public virtual Painting Cover { get; set; }
public int? CoverPaintingId { get; set; }
```

Note you can put the attribute either on the virtual property on the foreign key - just need to specify the name of the "other one".

*However*, since you will have two relationships between the same set of entities, you won't be able to do this without disabling Cascading deletes on one or both of them.  This can only be done using the [Fluent Configuration API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/hh134698.aspx).

```
public class Gallery
{
    public int GalleryId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("CoverPaintingId")]
    public virtual Painting Cover { get; set; }
    public int? CoverPaintingId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("SliderPaintingId")]
    public virtual Painting Slider { get; set; }
    public int? SliderPaintingId { get; set; }

}

public class Painting
{
    public int PaintingId { get; set; }
}

public class MyContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Gallery> Galleries { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Painting> Paintins { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Gallery>().HasOptional(g => g.Cover).WithMany().WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
        modelBuilder.Entity<Gallery>().HasOptional(g => g.Slider).WithMany().WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
    }
}
```

If you don't want the foreign key properties to exist in your code model, you can also configure these by using [.Map(...)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.modelconfiguration.configuration.foreignkeynavigationpropertyconfiguration.map%28v=vs.103%29) before the .[WillCascadeOnDelete(false)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg679204%28v=vs.103%29.aspx) part of the API instead of using ForeignKey.  I prefer to use Foreign Key, but here's how the code would look if you wanted to do it this way:

```
public class Gallery
{
    public int GalleryId { get; set; }
    public virtual Painting Cover { get; set; }
    public virtual Painting Slider { get; set; }
}

public class Painting
{
    public int PaintingId { get; set; }
}

public class MyContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Gallery> Galleries { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Painting> Paintins { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Gallery>().HasOptional(g => g.Cover).WithMany().Map(m => m.MapKey("CoverPaintingId")).WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
        modelBuilder.Entity<Gallery>().HasOptional(g => g.Slider).WithMany().Map(m => m.MapKey("SliderPaintingId")).WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
    }
}
```

Comment: I had tried that too Richard, but I received the following error: 

Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint 'FK_Galleries_Paintings_CoverPaintingId' on table 'Galleries' may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths. Specify ON DELETE NO ACTION or ON UPDATE NO ACTION, or modify other FOREIGN KEY constraints.
Could not create constraint. See previous errors.

Comment: Ah yes, forgot you'd get that with multiple relationships.  Updated the answer to explain how to get around that.

Comment: Richard. Made some progress, thanks, but now I'm getting the following error: The ForeignKeyAttribute on property 'Cover' on type 'ap.Models.Gallery' is not valid. The foreign key name 'CoverPaintingId' was not found on the dependent type 'ap.Models.Painting'. The Name value should be a comma separated list of foreign key property names.

And from what the error says, I understand I'd have to create a CoverPaintingId property on Painting? That'd not be what I wanted, since I only want to name the column that is already been creating on Gallery as "CoverPaintingId" instead of "Cover_PaintingId"

Comment: Try again now.  I often get confused by the .WithMany() and .WithRequired() options, and I used the wrong one.  I've put this code into a sample and it looks right to me.

Comment: You're the man Richard, it worked now. Thanks for taking the time to help!

Comment: I've also added the code for doing it completely in the Fluent API now, just for completeness.  You can swap `HasOptional` for `HasRequired` as necessary.

Comment: Props to Richard for explaining both ways to solve the problem!

Answer (score 0):

you could try to use [inverseproperty] decoration to achieve this.

Comment: Clot, I believe is for when you have inverted relationships and to tell EF not to create double FK relationships. I am actually using that, but for the Paintings property in the Gallery class. 

InverseProperty would not work for what I want to do. I do need those columns in Gallery, I just want to name them differently.